# Getting GET request string in jQuery

Tags: jquery, webforms

suppose I have a form:

```
<form id="someform" action="some.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="somename" />
    <input type="text" name="othername" />
    ...
    <input id="submitId" type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

And I want to get the request string generated by this:

```
?somename=blabla&othername=blablabla&submit=OK
```

Can I get this without actually submitting the form?

```
$('#submitId').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //... what to do here?
});
```

Another one, if I have the request string, can I put them to the form? (reversed).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('#submitId').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$('#someform').serialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try [jQuery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$('#someform').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to submit form using jQuery. You can use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like this:

```
jQuery('#someform').live('submit',function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // get action from form tag
        type: 'GET', // GET method
        data: $(this).serialize(), // Get form values
        success: function( response ) {
            alert( response ); // response from action script
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now in `some.php` action you can get form values like this:

```
echo $_GET['somename'];
echo $_GET['othername'];
```